# As I send list link to requests.get (). content Python?

Tags: python

I am sending an extracted list with xpath but it doesn't work with xpath

it works like this  **URL1**

```
url = ['http://images/productos/on-line/items/large/nb/de/nbdell1tc73.jpg',
       'http://images/productos/on-line/items/large/nb/de/nbdell1tc73_1.jpg',
       'http://images/productos/on-line/items/large/nb/de/nbdell1tc73_2.jpg',
       'http://images/productos/on-line/items/large/nb/de/nbdell1tc73_3.jpg' 
      ]
```

it does not work  **URL2**

```
url = sel.xpath('//section[@class="product-images js-product-images-container"]//img/@src')
```

result  url.path

```
 'url': ['http://images/productos/on-line/items/large/nb/de/nbdell1tc73.jpg',
         'http://images/productos/on-line/items/large/nb/de/nbdell1tc73_1.jpg',
         'http://images/productos/on-line/items/large/nb/de/nbdell1tc73_2.jpg',
         'http://images/productos/on-line/items/large/nb/de/nbdell1tc73_3.jpg'],
```

this code recepte the url

```
    i = 0
    for url22 in url:
        try:

            imagen_content = requests.get(url22).content
            image_file = io.BytesIO(imagen_content)
            imagen = Image.open(image_file).convert('RGB')
            path = './imagenes/' + '_' + str(i) + '.jpg'
            with open(path, 'wb')as f:
                imagen.save(f, "JPEG", quality=85)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
            print("ERROR")
        i += 1
```

With the first url it works, with the second one it doesn't.
How do I make it work with **url2**?

Comment: it turned out, I need to put url.get () url22.get()

Answer (score 0):

it turned out, I need to put url.get () url22.get()

i = 0
for url22 in url:
try:

```
        imagen_content = requests.get(url22.get()).content
        image_file = io.BytesIO(imagen_content)
        imagen = Image.open(image_file).convert('RGB')
        path = './imagenes/' + '_' + str(i) + '.jpg'
        with open(path, 'wb')as f:
            imagen.save(f, "JPEG", quality=85)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        print("ERROR")
    i += 1
```